# how to automatically mount ~/Private using ecryptfs when logging in via ssh pubkey

Tags: ssh, debian, ssh-keys, ecryptfs

Raionale: I want to be able to automatically make backups to a remote machine, which will be encrypted with ecryptfs.

The title says it all:

I set up ecryptfs-utils on my Debian Squeeze box, and set up one user to use it via `ecryptfs-setup-private`. When I log in via SSH using password authentication, the ~/Private directory automatically gets mounted.

How can I achieve that `~/Private` also automatically gets mounted when logging in via SSH using public key authentication? Obviously, the best solution would be if ecryptfs could somehow 'use' the SSH public key to en/decrypt the data (I know that then using the user's password would not be able to en/decrypt the data any more; this would be acceptable). Probably, this will not work. So perhaps somehow call `ecryptfs-mount-private` via *ssh* before logging in via public key? Probably, then I would need to somehow pipe the passphrase through the SSH connection, right? So I would need to store it on the source machine's file system. Not nice either.
Any other ideas?

Answer (score 2):

You will have to either store the password to disk, or provide it when SSH'ing. There is no other reliable way.

(`sshd` does not know your *private* key, it can only ask the client for proof that you have it.)

Comment: thanks, that's what i feared. i know sshd doesn't _know_ the private key; i simply had the hope that ecryptfs would somehow integrate with sshd to uncrypt.